# If I charge a electrolytic capacitor outside of a circuit and let it sit

Tags: capacitor, charge, electrolytic-capacitor

If I charge a electrolytic capacitor outside of a circuit and let it sit on my bench top, it drains over time.   I found this [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32529/do-capacitors-automatically-release-their-energy-over-time) on S.E. but that capacitor is in-circuit.

1. **Where does that charge go?**
2. **Does it get transformed into some type of energy and then lost over time?**

[image: Nichicon Capacitor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A real-word capacitor is not ideal. In this case the non-infinite resistance parallel to the ideal capacitor does its work: it let's the positve and negative charge cancel each other, generating heat in that resistor.

In practice you won't notice the heat, but the capacitor does heat up a tiny little bit.

Comment: I figured it was heat but the parallel resistance makes sense. Thank you.