# What resistor is needed to discharge a capacitor of about 3kV (inside a microwave)

Tags: capacitor, resistors, microwave, discharge

I've already made a capacitor discharge tool for a 300V capacitor and works fine using the 2 resistors that were on the PCB with the capacitor.

I need to upgrade this to discharge a microwave capacitor.

All I know about the capacitor inside is that they range from 1kV to 3.5kV capacitors, so  I would need to cover upto 3.5kV

What resistor would be suitable for this?

The tool I'm making/using is an insulated screwdriver rated 10kV, a
resistor, and a wire with a crocodile clip.

Comment: Any resistor that can handle up to 3.5 kV should be fine. Value depends on how fast you want to discharge it. Do you have a certain discharge current in mind, or certain discharge time in mind? The time would depend on how much capacitance you are discharging. To me it is unclear what actually you are asking? You need a suitable resistor but we don't know the your details what would be a suitable resistor.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281817/high-voltage-capacitor-discharge-tool
common problems have common answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High voltage capacitor discharge tool](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/281817/high-voltage-capacitor-discharge-tool)

Comment: hiya, time to discharge is not any issue, my tech guys can stand/wait 1 min 3 mins 5 mins, its all good, the important bit is just to discharge the cap safely.
thank you

Comment: also with resistor voltage value be able to handle the cap
would a hign voltage resistor still discharge a low voltage cap
i already brought one, CGS - TE CONNECTIVITY  HB310MFZRE  Resistor, 15kV dc 10M 4W
but when hooked up, did not discharge my test capacitor of 300v?

Answer (score 1):

> *What resistor would be suitable for this?*

**Example:**

If the internal capacitor were 1 μF then, the energy stored (for a terminal voltage of 3,500 volts) would be 6.125 joules. That's found using this formula: -

$$\text{energy} = C\cdot\dfrac{V^2}{2}$$

So, if you discharged that capacitor in one tenth of a second, the average power dissipation would be 61.25 watts. Given that you need 5 X CR to equal 0.1 seconds (99.3% discharge a capacitor), for a 1 μF capacitor the resistor value needs to be 100 kΩ.

In summary, you need to find a resistor that can dispense 6.125 joules of heat reliably in 0.1 seconds. It also needs to be able to handle a peak power of 122.5 watts - that's 3,500 squared divided by 100 k.

Your resistor needs to be rated to adequately work with the voltage it is subject to.

If you are repeatedly charging and discharging the capacitor, then you need to rate the resistor at a higher power because it will warm-up to a higher temperature each time it discharged the capacitor because the resistor would restart the process at an elevated temperature. A higher power rating resistor warms less for a given power.

Comment: ty, ive been reading many posts...
found a resistor with the following  spec.

HTS 15 CYLINDRICAL THICK FILM RESISTOR
Power Dissipation: 1.5 watts
Value Range: From 100K to 500M
Tolerance Options: From ±0.5% to ±10%
TCR Options: ±75ppm/°C
Maximum Voltage: 4kVdc
Dielectric Strength: >500Vrms

when you talk about watts and the above is only 1.5 i assume this is no good then?